# How can I make Raspberry Pi's Bluetooth discoverable to iPhone?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I've got a Raspberry Pi 4B,
when I use an Android phone to connect to the Pi with Bluetooth, it works normally, both pairing and connection.
But when I use an iPhone to do the same thing, the phone can not see Pi's Bluetooth, it means, the Pi's Bluetooth is not discoverable to iPhone.
(However, the iPhone's Bluetooth is dicoverable to  raspberry, but this is not what I need.)

Could anyone tell me, is there anything special of iPhone's Bluetooth?
What should I do if I want to make Pi's Bluetooth discoverable to iPhone?
I want to connect to Pi's Bluetooth from iPhone.

Update according to ukBaz's advice,
I am not sure what to do with Bluetooth next, but first I want to let iPhone pair with the Pi, now iPhone simply can not find the Pi's Bluetooth.

The way I make Pi to be discoverable is to run a shell script when Pi starts, through correcting the file /etc/rc.local.
the content of shell script is something like below,

```
sudo bluetoothctl << EOF  
discoverable on
pairable on
exit
```

Comment: Bluetooth covers both Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth Low Energy each having their own distinct protocols. That said you may have better luck with [RaspberryPi Stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=iphone%20bluetooth)

Comment: What is it you are trying to do with your Bluetooth connection? Is it audio? Or are you exposing some other Bluetooth service on the Raspberry Pi that you want the iPhone to connect to? How are you turning on `discover` on the Raspberry Pi. Maybe you can update your question with more information?

Comment: to Morrison Chang :Thanks for your guidance, I'll search this topic there, too.

Comment: to ukBaz: Updated. Can you give some more suggestions?

Comment: As far as I know, iphone is made to connect bluetooth with only another apple product, for example you can't pair iphone with android smartphone. Maybe there is a hack, maybe something changed last time, I don't know.

Comment: to Adrian: So I cannot let iPhone to  be the Central and  connect to raspberry Pi who works as Peripheral?

Comment: @ning, Try using the nRF Connect app to scan for and connect to the Raspberry Pi https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile

Comment: to ukBaz: Thansk. I've tried nRF to scan for Raspberry Pi, but still failed, the bluetooth of Pi is not discoverable to nRF, either. Maybe as somebody else said, I should do some iOS development to let it find Pi's bluetooth  rather than some simple settings or scripts.

Comment: See the answer I have posted over at: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/116824/121848

Comment: to ukBaz: Thank you very much.

Comment: to ukBaz: I did make raspberry Pi Bluetooth discoverable to iOS according https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51134/connect-an-iphone-to-a-pi-3b-with-bluetooth-low-energy/116824#116824.There are two questions that I want to ask: First, I can not see raspberry Pi Bluetooth in settings->Bluetooth of iOS,  can I do sth. to see it without nRF? Second, what does the string mean that comes after btmgmt ? "sudo btmgmt add-adv -u feaa -d 1016aafe100001626c7565746f6f746800 -g 1" or where can I get information about this? I am new to both Bluetooth and Raspberry Pi.